# Listbox not shows the updated/ newly added value in silverlight mvvm with Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

In my Silverlight5 with MVVM pattern project I have one listbox.
I load the data to listbox using entityframework. Initially all data are load into listbox without fail using entity framework model.
But if I add new data, the listbox doesn’t show the newly added value. But the newly added value is available in entity.
What is the problem? What I have to do to achieve this.

Listbox xaml coding:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Project,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" >
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />-->

                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="2,2,2,2"  BorderThickness="0">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Viewmodel Code:

```
    private IEnumerable<Project> projects;
        private Project project;
        private Customer customer;


        PartsDomainContext _context;
        public IEnumerable<Project> Projects
        {
            get
            {
                return projects;
            }
            set
            {
                projects= value;
                if (projects != null)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
                    Project = projects.FirstOrDefault();
                    OnPropertyChanged("Project");
                }
            }
        }
public Project Project
        {
            get
            { 
                return project;
            }
            set
            {
                project=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Project");
                if (project != null)
                {   

                    Customer = project.CustomerProjects.FirstOrDefault().Customer;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
                }
            }
        }
public ProjectListViewModel()
        {
            GetProjectList(ActiveData.Instance.userid);
        }
public void GetProjectList(int userid)
        {
            _context = new PartsDomainContext();
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            _context.Load(_context.GetProjectListQuery(ActiveData.Instance.userid), Param =>
                {
                    if (!Param.HasError)
                    {
                        Projects = Param.Entities;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
                    }
                }, null);
        }


public void GetProjectList(int userid)
        {
            _context = new PartsDomainContext();
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            _context.Load(_context.GetProjectListQuery(ActiveData.Instance.userid), Param =>
                {
                    if (!Param.HasError)
                    {
                        Projects = Param.Entities;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
                    }
                }, null);

        }
```

Need Help to solve it..!

Comment: Are you receiveing any message in the Output window? Does the _context.Load second argument run in another thread?

Comment: No Joan.. actuallu the entity contains value but the UI doesn't reflect that value in Listbox

Comment: Have you tried changing IEnumerable<Project> Projects to ObservableCollection<Project> Projects? Observable collections automatically update new data that is added or old data that is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In this code, the saveChanges() is not implemented anywhere. It should be adapted to your needs.

**UPDATE2: I forgot to mention how to create the databinding from your view to viewmodel.
This can be used with UserControls just the same. The UnityContainer will resolve all the dependencies automatically. In your codebehind, you will change your constructor to:**

```
public MainWindow(ProjectViewModel projectViewModel)
{
    this.DataContext = projectViewModel;
}
```

I think that first of all you should do some refactoring, extract some interfaces, create a repository and implement inversion of control in order to eliminate all these dependencies.

Let me help you with some code:
(First, I'm not sure how you are implementing your entity context, I like the Code First approach of Entity Framework very much, and I will be using (kindof) to demonstrate)

Your object probably looks somewhat like this.

```
public class Project
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

Then you have your context and its interface:

(This one is very simple, demonstrative, and using Code First, as I said above)

```
public interface IProjectContext
{
  DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectContext : DbContext, IProjectContext
{
  public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you should not have these Get methods on your ViewModel. Instead, let's extract them into a Repository implemantation (with its interface).

```
public interface IProjectRepository
{
  Project[] GetAll();
  Project[] GetByUser(int userId);
  void Add(Project project);
  void Remove(ProjectRepository project);
}

public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
  private IProjectContext context;

  public ProjectRepository(IProjectContext context)
  {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public Project[] GetAll()
  {
    return context.Projects.ToArray();
  }

  public Project[] GetByUser(int userId)
  {
    return context.Projects.Where(p => p.UserId == userId).ToArray();
  }

  public void Add(Project project)
  {
    context.Projects.Add(project);
  }

  public void Remove(Project project)
  {
    context.Projects.Remove(project);
  }
}
```

Your ViewModel now will be much simpler. And in order to make the twoway binding update correctly and on time, we will implement INotifyPropertChanged

```
public class ProjectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  #region Property Changed
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, e);
    }
  }
  protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
  {
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
  #endregion

  private IProjectRepository projectRepository;
  private ICollection<Project> projects;
  private Project activeProject;

  public ICollection<Project> Projects
  {
    get { return projects; }
    set
    {
      projects = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("Projects");
    }
  }

  public Project ActiveProject
  {
    get { return activeProject; }
    set
    {
      activeProject = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("ActiveProject");
    }
  }

  public ProjectViewModel(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
  {
    this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
    Projects = projectRepository.GetAll();
    ActiveProject = Projects.FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

I would implement the Unity Container in your App.xaml.cs in order to connect all these pieces together. To do that, you will have to override OnStartup and register the types above.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  protected override OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    private IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProjectRepository,ProjectRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IProjectContext,ProjectContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    MainWindow window = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    window.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hai just now i fixed this one.. write the DataContext with in ListBox_loaded() Event.

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new UrViewModel();
        }
```

Problem Solved..

Comment: Probably the worst possible solution.

Comment: Wat to do.. @sometimes this only helps Mr.JoanComasFdz :)

Comment: Try the approach I described. It's a very clean, MVVM oriented approach.
What you are doing in your code will 100% sure cause you problems later on. You are creating an instance of your viewmodel, and setting it as datacontext in your codebehind, on the load event of an object. It's an awful solution, that will, again, cause problems.

Comment: @JasperManickaraj I will definetely at least try what willmichels proposed.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz mine too trying willmichels approach

Comment: @JasperManickaraj Did you have any issues? Were you able to make it work?